# Airflow_dag dependency

Tags: dependencies, scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there any way where I can check and trigger a dag only of the previous run of the dag(previous scheduled run) us successfull ?

I want to check the status of previous run of the dag and then proceed with the new airflow dag.

Im new to airflow